# No duplicate names depending on other field

Tags: trigger

I have a doubt on triggers. I have a object as Hospital__c. zipcode__c is a field in hospital. A zipcode should have only one hospital name. If increase error should throw. How to solve this using trigger?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Why not use a Duplicate Rule?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
trigger DuplicateZipCode on Hospital__c (Before Insert , Before Update) {
    Double zipCode;    
    for(Hospital__c h : Trigger.New){ 
        zipCode = h.Zip_Code__c;    
    }

    List<Hospital__c> hospList = [SELECT id , Name , Zip_Code__c FROM Hospital__c WHERE Zip_Code__c =: zipCode];
    if(hospList.size()>0){
        for(Hospital__c h : Trigger.New){
            h.Zip_Code__c.addError('Hospital ZipCode should be unique.');
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this code for your scenario. This Trigger for Every Hospital's zipcode should be unique.